# Numero float comparado com uma soma não confere?

Tags: php

```
$a=3787.97;
$b=3000.00+787.97;

echo $a . " # ". $b . "</br>";

var_dump($a==$b);
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

Resultado :

```
3787.97 # 3787.97
bool(false) float(3787.97) float(3787.97)
```

Por que `bool(false)`?